# Is this a sign of a bad drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware

```
smartctl --attributes --log=selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-379.22.1.lve1.2.17.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   138   137   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4100
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       1872
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   103   103   000    Old_age   Always       -       40
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1856         -
```

Comment: What sign exactly — there're signs, lot of them :-P

Comment: Just wondering how do you tell? Is the reaming 00% bad?

Comment: Reason I ask is I had this drive replaced after a huge I/O melt down and now I still see random I/O spikes that should not be there

Answer (score 1):

The is no signs of bad with this hard drive. The lines

```
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1856         -
```

tel you that it did an extended offline test at the age of 1856 days and completed it without error. The remaining 00% means that the test is over.

The

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
```

shows that there is no bad sectors on the disk so it didn't had to reallocate it. And the other readings seems also fine.

If you want to make yourself calm run a long test with

```
smartctl --test=long /dev/sda
```

and then check the readings again if it runs without error then everything is fine.

By the way running short tests in a daily and long tests on a weekly basis is a good habit.